# Deploying jars for User Defined Functions

Tags: hive

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins

Hive provides a way to register user defined functions using the 'add jar' command, how should an application register these jars programatically?

If a particular class definition changes in the user defined function, should I have 'add jar' or is there a different command to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add hive udf jar from java code is,

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, "", "");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery("add jar /user/jars/HiveUdf.jar");
```